# How can I transfer a large directory between two servers that can't see each other directly?

Tags: bash, rsync, scp, curl

The server named SeesBoth sees both server A and server B.  A can see SeesBoth, but not B.  B can see SeesBoth, but not A.  (I'm told this is because of subnet masks.)

I have been tasked with copying a large directory, with many subdirectories, from A to B.  The guy who did this previously copied a small section at a time from A to SeesBoth, transferred it to B, copied another small section . . .  It took him days.

Is there an scp, or a curl, or an rsync command that will copy the data from A, pipe it through SeesBoth, and deposit it in the right format on B?

Comment: "Because of subnet masks" is at best inaccurate. It can certainly be due to subnets, but usually it's either a) because the two subnets are deliberately kept firewalled from each other for security reasons, or b) nobody knows how to configure the firewall to stop blocking communications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If scp is enough, then yes, OpenSSH has an option `scp -3` for this.

```
scp -3 user@hostA:/foo user@hostB:/foo
```

Alternatively, you can stream a *tar* or *cpio* archive between two SSH connections:

```
ssh user@hostA "cd /foo && tar -czf - ." | ssh user@hostB "cd /foo && tar -xvzf -"
```

Comment: Or you could set up SSH tunnels first and then run SCP or RSYNC through the tunnel.

Comment: scp -3 worked perfectly for me.   Thanks for your help.